# How can I debug pserve using Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pyramid

I'm getting started with Pyramid development on Windows. I have Python 2.7 installed. I used virtualenv to create a nice sandbox for my Pyramid app. I also created PyDev 2.4 on Eclipse Indigo. I also created a separate PyDev interpreter just for my virutalenv, so it should have access to all the directories.

I set up a new debug configuration.

- **Project**: testapp (the only project in the workspace)
- **Main module**: ${workspace_loc:testapp/Scripts/pserve-script.py}
- **Args**: development.ini
- **Working dir**: Other: ${workspace_loc:testapp/testapp}

When I hit Debug, the output is:

> pydev debugger: starting Starting server in PID 2208.
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Tools\eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR1-incubation-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__ Unhandled exception in thread started by
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Tools\eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR1-incubation-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__ self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by
>   File "C:\Tools\eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR1-incubation-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__
>   TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
>   self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs) :
>   File "C:\Tools\eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR1-incubation-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.3.0.2011121518\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__ self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>   TypeErrorThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
>   TypeError:  self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs) : ThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
>   TypeErrorThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple :
>   ThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
>   serving on http://0.0.0.0:6543

Even though it says the server is running, it's not. Nothing is listening on that port.

Any idea on how to fix this? Debugging certainly isn't necessary, but I like having a fully set up development environment. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, realized I didn't have PyDev 2.4 installed. I upgrade to 2.4 and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Pyramid includes remarkably good debug support in the form of the [debug toolbar](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html#the-debug-toolbar).

Make sure that the line

```
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar
```

in your `development.ini` isn't commented out to enable it.  It doesn't support Eclipse breakpoints, but gives almost everything else you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't gotten into that error, but usually, on difficult to debug environments, the remote debugger (http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) may be used (that way it works kind of like pdb: add code to add a breakpoint, so, until that point, your program runs as usual).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed these steps and added the `pydevd.settrace()` call in my Pyramid app's `__init__.py`. After following the steps Eclipse *will* break into the `__init__.py` right after the call to `pydevd.settrace()`. However, I set a breakpoint on my only view in `views.py` and hit continue, but that breakpoint is never hit (and of course I tried refreshing the browser to exercise that view routine again). The breakpoints window shows that `views.py` breakpoint as active, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Do you know if it's spawning a different process for the requests (in which case, pydevd.settrace must be called again in each process)...

Answer (score 0):

Pyramid's pserve seems to use multiple threads like Fabio suggests might be the case.  I found I could make breakpoints work by monkey-patching the ThreadTaskDispatcher before invoking pserve:

```
# Allow attaching PyDev to the web app
import sys;sys.path.append('..../pydev/2.5.0-2/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.4.0.201208051101/pysrc/')

# Monkey patch the thread task dispatcher, so it sets up the tracer in the worker threads
from waitress.task import ThreadedTaskDispatcher
_prev_start_new_thread = ThreadedTaskDispatcher.start_new_thread
def start_new_thread(ttd, fn, args):
    def settrace_and_call(*args, **kwargs):
        import pydevd ; pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    from thread import start_new_thread
    start_new_thread(settrace_and_call, args)
ThreadedTaskDispatcher.start_new_thread = start_new_thread
```

Note, I also tried:

```
set_trace(..., trace_only_current_thread=False)
```

But this either makes the app unusably slow, or doesn't work for some other reason.

Having done the above, when run the app will automatically register it with pydev debug server running locally.  See:
http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html